# Close popup window if user log out in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, iframe

In my application, has a page user can open an popup window. When user click logout it must close popup window.
I use a static variable for store popup window variable in `Global.ts` class

```
public static QUICKTREND : any;
```

In function to open popup window, i stored it

```
this.quickWin = window.open(URL, 'QuickTrend', 'width=' + w + ', 
height=' + h + ', left=' + x + ', top=' + y + ', location=no'+ ', status=no'); 
 Constants.QUICKTREND = this.quickWin;
```

In logout() function I get popup window and close

```
if(!isNullOrUndefined(Constants.QUICKTREND)){
       let currentIframe = Constants.QUICKTREND;
       currentIframe.close();
 }
```

**It worked correct if I did not refresh page.**

But when I refresh page, variable QUICKTREND reset to undefined.

I searched solution to keep variable if page is refresh, only solution to save to localStorage or sessionStorage. But this way, I can not save popup window object because it is DOM object, `Converting circular structure to JSON` error show.

```
localStorage.setItem("currentIframe", this.quickWin);
```

Is it possible to save popup window to localStorage?

How can I close popup window when I logout if page is refresh?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maintain reference to popup window over page refresh in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172526/maintain-reference-to-popup-window-over-page-refresh-in-javascript)

Comment: (Your code doesn't seem to have anything to do with iframes; they're not the same thing as popup windows.)

Comment: @Daniel Back my question is very different, angular vs javascript and refresh page

Comment: update content from iframe to popup window

Comment: Your question is identical to that question; angular is irrelevant to the answer -- the technique would be the same with or without the framework.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below code:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Angular-Experiment';

  public myWindow;
  private URL = 'https://www.google.com/';

  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  closeOnrefresh(event) {
    console.log('closeOnrefresh', event);
    if (this.myWindow && !this.myWindow.closed) {
      this.myWindow.close();
    }
  }

  openWindow() {
    console.log("open window");
    if (!this.myWindow || (this.myWindow && this.myWindow.closed)) {
      this.myWindow = window.open(this.URL, 'self', 'width=1000,height=1000');
    } else {
      this.myWindow.focus();
    }
  }

  Winfocus() {
    console.log("Winfocus");
    if (this.myWindow && !this.myWindow.closed) {
      // this.myWindow.close();// to close
      this.myWindow.focus();// to focus
    }
  }

  Logout() {
    console.log("WinLogout");
    if (this.myWindow && !this.myWindow.closed) {
      this.myWindow.close();// to close
    }
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<input type="button" value="Open" (click)="openWindow()">
<input type="button" value="focus" (click)="Winfocus()">
<input type="button" value="Logout" (click)="Logout()">
```

Comment: also i want close pop up only when user click logout

Comment: I use angular not javascript

Comment: The functions/elements used here are not specific to Javascript, these can be used in Angular also. At the end, angular code gets converted to javascript. So, I think that is not going to make much difference.

Comment: They are very different

Comment: Thanks for your sample Eashwar, but it not my requirement. I want it keep window popup after refresh page, only close when user click logout.